# How can I access function args passed to a Python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am using the following code (simplified for the sake of confidentiality) to run multiple threads in python.

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
for result in pool.map(my_function, [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    # do something with the result depending on which arguments the thread has used
```

Is there a way to access the arguments each thread used to get the `result` without having `my_function` return these as part of `result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, you can enumerate the results and match results to the original input.

```
arg1s = [1, 2, 3]
arg2s = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i, result in enumerate(pool.map(my_function, arg1s, arg2s)):
    # If i == 1, then result == my_function(1, 'a')
    # If i == 2, then result == my_function(2, 'b')
    # etc
    ...
```

(The documentation for `ProcessPoolExecutor` provides an [example of `map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example) that implies the results are returned in the same order that the arguments are used. I assume the same is true of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, since `map` is inherited from `Executor`. In fact, you could write a clunkier version of this to adhere more closely to that example:

```
for arg1, arg2, result in zip(arg1s, arg2s, pool.map(lambda x: my_function(*x), arg1s, arg2s)):
    # result == my_function(arg1, arg2)
```

)

Comment: Thank you chepner. The results are returned in the same order arguments are used indeed. I haven't tried the other solutions since that info already solved the problem at hand.